# Why doesn't the Tor bundle feature a track/spy blocker?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, add-on

Am I missing something or why is no spy/track blocker included in the browser bundle? I undestand that add-ons may weaken the anonymity/privacy but aren't the example add-ons below not trusted?

e.g. Disconnect
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disconnect/

or EFF's Privacy Badger https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/privacy-badger-firefox/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is effectively permanently in "private browsing mode" anyway, so it doesn't keep persistent cookies or any other data except for things explicitly done by the user e.g. bookmarks.

There's no cookies and no history in TBB.

Those extensions add nothing if you're already in private mode.